# ForceRTL on iOS isn't working in React Native App

Tags: reactjs, react-native, internationalization, i18next, react-i18next

Android is responding well to direction change, however iOS isn't switching RTL correctly, iOS keep restarting and when I checked the state of **isRTL** is doesn't change

```
 useEffect(() => {
    initializingSet(true);
    const languageSetter = async () => {
      const storageLang = await AsyncStorage.getItem("appLang");
      const systemLanguage = getLocales()[0].languageCode;
      const { isRTL } = I18nManager;
      console.log(
        storageLang,
        storageLang,
        appLang,
        I18nManager.isRTL,
        "<<=Lang"
      );
      if (appLang) {
        changeLanguage(appLang);
        if (appLang !== storageLang) {
          AsyncStorage.setItem("appLang", appLang);
        }
        if ((appLang === "en" && isRTL) || (appLang !== "en" && !isRTL)) {
          I18nManager.allowRTL(!isRTL);
          I18nManager.forceRTL(!isRTL); // FIXNOW: iOS not switching to RTL
          RNRestart.restart();
        }
        initializingSet(false);
      } else {
        if (storageLang) {
          appLangSet(storageLang as AppLanguagesType);
        } else {
          if (systemLanguage) {
            AsyncStorage.setItem("appLang", systemLanguage).finally(() =>
              appLangSet(systemLanguage as AppLanguagesType)
            );
          } else {
            appLangSet("en");
          }
        }
      }
    };

    languageSetter();
  }, [appLang]);
```

my app.json  has the `supportsRTL`

```
   "extra": {
      "supportsRTL": true,
           }
```

The same app run on Android just fine!
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After alot of search I found this issue
https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/26532

removing `expo-localization` fixed it, now I am using native modules to detect language

```
const systemLanguage = (
        (Platform.OS === "ios"
          ? NativeModules.SettingsManager.settings.AppleLocale ||
            NativeModules.SettingsManager.settings.AppleLanguages[0] //iOS 13
          : NativeModules.I18nManager.localeIdentifier) as string | undefined
      )?.substring(0, 2) as AppLanguagesType | undefined;
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to add it in AppDelegate.mm on iOS project.

```
#import <React/RCTI18nUtil.h>
...
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
...
 [[RCTI18nUtil sharedInstance] allowRTL:YES];
...
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately didn't resolve my issue

Comment: if you want RTL mode allowRTL:YES or allowRTL:NO.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing `i18n` in this line:    `changeLanguage(appLang)`

Replace it something like this:  `i18n.changeLanguage('ar')`

**Example My Language Switching Tabs:**

```
import React from 'react';
import {Text, View, Pressable, I18nManager} from 'react-native';
import {useDispatch, useSelector} from 'react-redux';
import {useTranslation} from 'react-i18next';
import {useInjectReducer} from 'redux-injectors';
import RNRestart from 'react-native-restart';

import {GlobalSelector} from '../../store/selector';
import globalReducer, {setLanguage} from '../../store/global';
import {SaveLanguage} from '../../utils/languageStorage';
import LanguageTabStyle from './style';
import AppColor from '../../constants/Colors';

const LanguageTabs = ({containerStyle}) => {
  const {t, i18n} = useTranslation();
  const {BLACK} = AppColor();

  useInjectReducer({key: 'global', reducer: globalReducer});

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const {language} = useSelector(GlobalSelector);
  const styles = LanguageTabStyle();

  return (
    <View style={[styles.mainContainer, {...containerStyle}]}>
      <Pressable
        onPress={async () => {
          i18n.changeLanguage('en');
          dispatch(setLanguage('English'));
          if (I18nManager.isRTL) {
            await I18nManager.forceRTL(false);
            await SaveLanguage('English');
            RNRestart.Restart();
          }
        }}
        style={
          language === 'English' ? styles.activeButton : styles.inActiveButton
        }>
        <Text style={[styles.text, {color: BLACK}]}>{t('English')}</Text>
      </Pressable>
      <Pressable
        onPress={async () => {
          i18n.changeLanguage('ar');
          dispatch(setLanguage('Arabic'));
          await SaveLanguage('Arabic');
          if (!I18nManager.isRTL) {
            await I18nManager.forceRTL(true);
            await SaveLanguage('Arabic');
            RNRestart.Restart();
          }
        }}
        style={
          language === 'Arabic' ? styles.activeButton : styles.inActiveButton
        }>
        <Text style={[styles.text, {color: BLACK}]}>{t('Arabic')}</Text>
      </Pressable>
    </View>
  );
};

export default LanguageTabs;
```

Hopefully it will help you.

Comment: I have  `changeLanguage(appLang);` which calls the i18n library